# UnderscoreJs Templating - What file extension should I use?

Tags: underscore.js, template-engine

With every template engine, I'm always confused with what file extension I should use. I never know where to find this kind of information. For example HandlebarsJs does not list what kind of extension we should use, and there are like 3 possible extensions you can use: tmpl, hdbs, etc.

Anyway, my question now is what extension I should use for Underscore mini template engine? I tried with a .txt and it worked, but I doubt it's the best way to do it. A normal html file would work?

Comment: Well, it would have a `text/whatever` mimetype, and I don't think there is anything specified. `.txt` sounds fine.

Comment: Yeah, I think I could put anything as the extension. Maybe they are only for the IDE.

Comment: For Underscore I prefer `tmpl`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you'll mostly be writing html in the file, I'd just use .html; that way, you won't have to reconfigure your webserver to serve it as a different kind of file either.

Alternatively, something I've used in another project, is to indicate it's a template by a double extension - filename.tpl.html for example. It will still be sent to the browser using a text/html MIME type, but for developers it'll remain obvious it's a template.